# Intercept popup notifications android

Tags: android, popup, notifications

Is an API available in android that would allow the interception/cancelling/redirecting of pop-up modal notifications?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer. No. You only have control over the modal dialog boxes that are generated within your own application.

Comment: hmmm, was really looking for something I could use to control popups from other apps. So I guess I have no options then?

Answer (score 0):

you could try overriding the activitys onPrepareDialog, which passes in the dialog, then use dialog.dismiss() or dialog.cancel() to cancel it.